# set Vertical Alignment for a <form> tag as a navbar item to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Know that the question in this type is frequently asked ,but I can't find my answer in results of my searches . So in my Razor View there is a navbar and it includes two items : 'Home' and 'Logout user' :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                    <li>
                        <form method="post" asp-action="logout" asp-controller="Account">
                            <button type="submit" class="navbar-link btn btn-link" >
                                    Logout  @User.Identity.Name
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>                     
                }
                else
                {
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a></li>
                }
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The Problem is that the 'Logout User' tag has not centeral vertical alignment and a little is upper than the 'Home' tag.

[image: Razor View]

How can I set the vertical alignment for the 'Logout user' tag to center ,so that this tag adjusts to the 'Home' tag?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the mighty Flexbox.

You may need to adjust this so it does *not* work for all your `.container` selectors but it should give you an idea :-)

```css
nav{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:red;
}
.container{
  height:100%;
}
.navbar-collapse{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:100%;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
ul:first-child{
  margin-left:25px;
}
ul:last-child{
  margin-right:25px;
}
*{
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                    <li>
                        <form method="post" asp-action="logout" asp-controller="Account">
                            <button type="submit" class="navbar-link btn btn-link" >
                                    Logout  @User.Identity.Name
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>                     
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have removed your .Net `if()` for clarity.

Comment: Thanks David , but that's not work for me . I changed my code like your code , but it doesn't work for me.